# Moles and licensing using file licenses.licx

Tags: moles, pex-and-moles, microsoft-fakes

I have problem with moles and file licenses.licx. I searched over internet, but haven't found a helping answer.

The problem is, that we are using licensed third party product library which needs license key stored in file licenses.licx. Let's call this product library Product.dll.

We have this file stored in Properties folder of project where we reference the licensed Product.dll. Let's  call this project Proj1.

Then we have unittest project (Proj1.UnitTest), where we reference project Proj1 and library Product.dll. Then we add moles assemblies for both of them, so we have referenced Proj1.Moles and Product.Moles.

If we run any test for method from Proj1 or Product without attribute [HostType("Moles")] the test passes without any problem.

But if we need to mole any method, and run the test method with attribute [HostType("Moles")], then the license dialog is displayed for each call of method from Product. This makes our unittesting not possible anymore.

Could you please help me with this problem?

I read on Pex and Moles webpage, that they're becoming part of MS VS 11.

Is there any other progress in development or bugfixing, except of integration in MS VS 11? Because and latest release is really old - 0.94.51023.0 from 11/1/2010.

Thanks in advance for you answer.

Regards

Jan.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last release in 2010 the mole and pex team was probably busy intergrating moles and pex in the new Visual Studio 2011. Moles should now be the **Fakes framework** in the Beta version. You can download the beta at the microsoft msdn site and see if that solves your problem.